# How to implement a reentrant locking mechanism through dispatch concurrent queue (GCD)?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have just read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494167/how-to-implement-a-reentrant-locking-mechanism-in-objective-c-through-gcd), and its solution seems convincing:

- Serial queue is used to synchronize access
- dispatch_get_specific/dispatch_set_specific is used to provide reentrance capability.

What I am interested at is if it is possible to advance this scheme to implement reentrant locking mechanism for **concurrent dispatch queue** (each read is done using dispatch_sync, write is done using dispatch_barrier_async, like is described [here, see "One Resource, Multiple Readers, and a Single Writer"](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/low-level-concurrency-apis.html)).

P.S. I think I've managed to implement this using `[NSThread currentThread].threadDictionary` [here](https://github.com/stanislaw/SafeObject/blob/master/SafeObject/SafeObject.m), but I don't like dealing with `[NSThread currentThread]` since I rely on GCD. Is it possible to replace the usage of `[NSThread currentThread].threadDictionary` with some tricky `dispatch_set_specific/dispatch_get_specific` code?

Comment: This post is a little old but, is there any reason why you can't just use dispatch_get_specific for what you're trying to do?  If you create a concurrent dispatch queue (instead of using a global one), wouldn't you just do the same thing?

Comment: @JPC, seems that you're right. Too long to describe my mistake (why I felt it was a different case)... Feel free to format this your comment as an answer and I will accept it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for this by the way! I can now revisit my original code and eliminate all this [NSThread currentThread] stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You asked me in a comment on the linked post if I would comment on this question. Sorry I took so long, but I remember the first time I looked at it I didn't feel like I had anything productive say. But I was reminded of this topic today and came back across this question and figured I'd take a shot:

In general, I would suggest not going down this road at all. As I explained in [the linked-to/from answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19495517/438982), implementing a recursive "lock" with `dispatch_get/set_specific` is *never* bulletproof, and going beyond the simple, serial case to the one-writer/many-readers semantic of `dispatch_barrier_[a]sync` isn't going to remove those problems, and would probably introduce even more issues.

As an aside, if you're just looking for an alternative to `[NSThread threadDictionary]` for thread-local storage, perhaps in the form of a non-Objective-C API, then you should use `pthread_setspecific` and `pthread_getspecific`. These are the lower level POSIX calls upon which `[NSThread threadDictionary]` is (almost certainly) built.

Stepping back for a minute: There is a pretty strong sentiment among veteran systems programmers that recursive locks are an anti-pattern from the get-go, and are to be avoided. Here is an [interesting treatise on the subject](http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html). (If you aren't interested in the apocryphal tale of why recursive mutexes exist in POSIX, just search for "the objective facts" to jump to the part that's relevant to this question.) That piece is written in terms of more primitive "locks" (made up of mutexes and conditions), which are fundamentally different from queues, despite the fact that queues can be (sometimes quite usefully) adapted to simulate locks in some common cases. However, even though they're different, if you consider the criticisms Butenhof levies against recursive primitive locks, it quickly becomes evident that in many of the ways that recursive locks are "bad", using queues to simulate locks is *worse*. For instance, at the most basic level, the only way you can unlock a lock-simulated-by-a-queue is to return; there is **no other way** to release a queue-based lock. Calling out to other code which may need to recursively re-enter that lock, while the caller continues to hold it, is a potentially unbounded extension of the time the "lock" is held.

A piece of general advice that has served me well is, "Use the highest level abstraction that gets the job done." In the context of this question, that would translate to (setting aside the aforementioned criticisms of recursive locking for the moment): If you're working in Objective-C and, for whatever reason, you want recursive locks, just use `@synchronized`. When performance analysis tells you that your use of `@synchronized` is actually causing you a problem, *then* look into better solutions (with the foresight to know that "better solutions" will probably require moving away from recursive locks all together.)

In sum, trying to adapt GCD's concurrent queue barrier behavior to simulate a recursive reader/writer lock feels like a losing proposition. At best, it would always be subject to the limitations that I explained [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19495517/438982) for the serial case. At worst, you're promulgating a pattern that ultimately reduces concurrency.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, @ipmcc! I need some time to read & understand all the things you've pointed me to. By the way, you are one of the best writers here on SO.